# Can anyone find equivalent c# code

Tags: c#, pinvoke

This is c++ code `CreateImageSnapshot, (int, eImageFormat, BYTE**)` in VC++ we implementing
 `BYTE**`

```
PlayerLib::CreateImageSnapshot (iPlayerRef,static_cast<eImageFormat>(lFormat),
        &pBuffer);
```

here i need to import the dll and do the same process in c#.. Can anyone find equivalent C# code like

```
[DllImport("PlayerLib", SetLastError = false, 
                   EntryPoint = "CreateImageSnapshot")]
public static extern int CreateImageSnapshot(...);
```

Here I need to extern the CreateImageSnapshot function and I want to know how to pass the argument

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in you previous question the definition will be:

```
[DllImport("PlayerLib", SetLastError = false, EntryPoint = "CreateImageSnapshot")]
public static extern int CreateImageSnapshot(int player, eImageFormat imgFormat,
                                             ref IntPtr imgBuffer);


byte[] img;
IntPtr imgBuff = new IntPtr();

int res = CreateImageSnapshot(1, eImageFormat.jpeg, ref imgBuff);
int size = ????
if (res > 0)
{
  img = new byte[size];
  Marshal.Copy(imgBuff, img, 0, size);
}
```

but you unmanaged function does not returns the size of buffer. you need to add one more parameter to your func or return array lenth in res.

Comment: k Tror how can i call this function 

CreateImageSnapshot(1,imgFormat.jpeg, ? ); 
how to pass the byte array argument

Comment: you have to pass: 
IntPtr buffer = new IntPtr();

Comment: k fine it's returns some location.. how can change that pointer to 
byte[] array

Comment: to convert IntPtr to byte[] you need to copy it from unmanaged memory to managed. byte[] arrayRes = new int[size]; Marshal.Copy(imgBuffer, arrayRes, 0, size);. But you also need to get from this function the size of buffer. Without it you can't copy yur array

Comment: IntPtr buffer = new IntPtr();

            int[] arrayRes = new int[size];
            Marshal.Copy(buffer, arrayRes, 0, size);


is't correct code

Comment: ok my need is i need to send byte[] to that function  and it ll return the some image bytes . simpily i have to save that image in my local path

Comment: you cant pass simply byte[] because your unmanaged function needs reference to byte array. The only one solution is to pass IntPtr and then copy from it to your managed array. But as I said your function must return the size of unmanaged array.

Comment: hi tror i have lot of problem in my module... i need your help man... if you can means give your mail id .